# Big-O of `2n-2n^3`

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

I am working on an assignment but a friend of mine disagree with the answer to one part.

```
f(n) = 2n-2n^3
```

I find the complexity to be `f(n) = O(n^3)`

Am I wrong?

Comment: `f(n)` is strictly non-positive for non-negative `n`, so `f(n) = O(1)` is true as well.

Comment: @chepner please note that OP is asking for the reverse and thus even 1 does not belong to `O(f(n))`.

Comment: I'm assuming `O(f(n)) = n^3` is incorrect use of the notation; I've never seen big-o notation used on the left-hand sign. The question is likely "Find a function `g` such that `f=O(g)`, and a monotonically decreasing function that is always negative for `n > 0` has any positive constant function as a bound.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't wrong, since O(n^3) does not provide a tight bound. However, typically you assume that `f` is increasing and try to find the smallest function `g` for which `f=O(g)` is true. Consider a simple function `f=n+3`. It's correct to say that `f=O(n^3)`, since `n+3 < n^3` for all `n > 2` (just to pick an arbitrary constant). However, it's "more" correct to say that `f=O(n)`, since `n+3 < 2n` for all `n > 3`, and this gives you a better feel for how `f` behaves as `n` increases.

In your case, `f` is *decreasing* as `n` increases, so it is true that `f = O(g)` for *any* function that stays positive as `n` increases. The "smallest" (or rather, slowest growing) such function is a constant function for some positive constant, and we usually write that as `2n - 2n^3 = O(1)`, since `2n - 2n^3 < 1` for all `n>0`.

You could even find some function of `n` that is decreasing as `n` increases, but decreases more slowly than your `f`, but such usage is rare. Big-O notation is most commonly used to describe algorithm running times as the input size increases, so `n` is almost universally assumed to be positive.